# Unable to Compile in magento2

Tags: magento2, compilation

i'm unable to compile in magento2 if i run the Compile command always give the result like below

```
[dsdfsd@srv2 www]$ php bin/magento setup:di:compile
Compilation was started.
Proxies code generation... 0/7 [>---------------------------]   0% < 1 
sec 52.0 MiB
[dsdfsd@srv2 www]$
```

Struck in Proxies code Generation. Anyone please help me solve this... thanks in Advance

Comment: Try to clean without `.htaccess` the content of `var/generated` or `generated`

Comment: sorry i can't understand.. clean without .htaccess means?

Comment: In `var/generated` folder you find some files and an `.htaccess` so remove all the files inside `var/generated` without the `.htaccess`

Answer (score 0):

Check any third-party or custom extensions that you have added to ensure that there are no errors in etc/di.xml.

Delete the contents of the generated/* folder.

Delete the contents of the var/di/* folder.

Delete var/cache/*

Check to see if it's working after all of the above: php bin/magento setup:di:compile

Comment: i had tried this... but still compilation not occurs